# SQL Constraints using triggers - are race conditions possible?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, constraints, race-condition, sql-server-2017

This is just an example, but it hopefully illustrates the question - imagine I want to limit a table to ten rows, and create an `AFTER INSERT` trigger that `count(...)`s the rows in the table, rolling back the transaction if there are more than 10.

Is it possible to have a race condition where two transactions `INSERT`, both see the count is OK (because neither has committed), and then both commit, with the limit exceeded?

Would adding a `with(nolock)` in the trigger's `count(...)` query mean that at least both would fail (as they would see each other's uncommitted row)?

Comment: i think the second query will wait till the first one ends.

Comment: This is painfully easy to test. I would strongly advise not to use NOLOCK especially when you want accuracy.

Comment: What happens when you try?   Seems to me that adding a table lock would prevent this from happening.